# Migrating a Jest Mock Function to Vitest

Tags: ts-jest, vitest

I have the following test where I am defining a mocked function using a jest.MockedFunction type:

```
  const mockedUseAppState = AppState.useAppState as jest.MockedFunction<
    typeof AppState.useAppState
  >;
```

how can I do this to be compatible with Vitest?